# Use drawable resources for Gboard sticker pack

Tags: android

Is it possible to use drawable resources bundled in your app instead of hosted images for adding stickers to Gboard?

Google provides the following code snippet [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/09/create-stickers-for-gboard-on-google.html) to show how to add a sticker to Gboard and it looks like the only way is to reference a hosted image:

```
new Indexable.Builder("Sticker")
.setName("Bye")
// add url for sticker asset 
.setImage("http://www.snoopysticker.com?id=1234")
// see: Support links to your app content section
.setUrl("http://sticker/canonical/image/bye")
// Set the accessibility label for the sticker.
.setDescription("A sticker for Bye")
// Add search keywords.
.put("keywords", "bye", "snoopy", "see ya", "good bye")
.put("isPartOf",
    new Indexable.Builder("StickerPack")
      .setName("Snoopy Pack")
      .build())
.build())};
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String drawableResourceUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.name/drawable/yourfilenamewithoutextension").toString());
```

Add this string to your setUrl() method.

Answer (score 0):

Google's AppIndexing [sample project](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/app-indexing/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/app_indexing/AppIndexingUtil.java) has an example of the files being generated at run time. This isn't exactly a `Drawable` resource but the same strategy can likely be used.